# Regular expression and Date selecting

Tags: r, regex, date

I have the data with this date format: 01.01.1981 to 31.10.2005.
But I have to select just the data from May to September for each year. 01.05 to 30.09
How can I write the script in Rstudio??? I am using windows 8.

Comment: I found the answer: ".[0-3][0-9].[0][5-9]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Rstudio, but this is the regular expression that will match those dates:

```
\d{2}\.0[5-9]\.\d{4}
```